# Stop JVM windows process if caller of ShellExecuteEx dies

Tags: java, windows, jna, elevated-privileges

I created a java library which elevates a java application run from a JAR with administrator privileges. On linux this works fine, and if I exit the application by hitting CTRL-C in linux the elevated application started with sudo stops as expected. On windows this is not the behavior. When I exit with CTRL-C the administrator process keeps running and I need to manually stop it from the task manager.

See the code @ https://github.com/rritoch/super-user-application/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vnetpublishing/java/suapp/WinSudo.java

How can I get the process which was created using JPA/ShellExecuteEx to automatically terminate if the calling process dies, such as when the user exits by typing CTRL-C?

Comment: Add the process handle to a [job object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161) that's configured with `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE`.

Comment: eryksun, I added a job object as you suggested and it still doesn't work. From what I can tell from my research is that ShellExecuteEx is probably not setting CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB and I don't see any options to do so. I have committed the code with your suggestion but it still isn't working.

Comment: You're not checking for errors, so how do you know whether it was successfully added and configured? You should first call `QueryInformationJobObject` to get and then modify the current `JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation` (9). Make sure it's the extended information; you're currently setting `JobObjectBasicLimitInformation` (2).

Comment: eryksun, I added comprehensive error checking, added a QueryInformationJobObject call, and changed to JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation (9) as you suggested and even though each function call is successful the child (Admin) process is still not terminating when the parent (User) process terminates.

Comment: eryksun, I think it should be possible to serialize the current process handle and pass it as a command line argument to the child process and have the parent process deserialize it and run an interval to exit if the parent process closes, but I also can't find a way to serialize/deserialize the process handle returned by GetCurrentProcess()

Comment: Are you using Windows 8? That adds job hierarchies. In Windows 7 a process can only belong to a single job. I don't know how a ancestor job might influence `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE`. I suppose you could respawn the parent process using `CreateProcess` and `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB`.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution to this problem I have added a shutdown hook to end the child process. This is not an ideal solution because if the parent process is forcibly exited the shutdownHook won't be run and the child process continues running, but this does handle the CTRL-C initiated exit.

```
    final HANDLE childProcess = execInfo.hProcess;

    Thread shutdownHook = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Terminating child process");
            Kernel32.INSTANCE.TerminateProcess(childProcess, 0);
            Kernel32X.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(childProcess);
            Kernel32X.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(hJob);
        }
    };

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(shutdownHook);
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I having a similar problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498555/jna-in-windows-auto-terminate-child-processes-using-windows-jobs

Comment: No, this is the best I could come up with

Comment: I solved my problem, take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498555/jna-in-windows-auto-terminate-child-processes-using-windows-jobs